# Excel formula to search and with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I badly need a formula that has the below requirement

In Col A i have either "business" or "brw" or it is blank

Col B has a big statement or line and somewhere in the line it has a couple of question marks("??")

What i need is 
If A1 does not have "business" C1 needs to return a blank (nothing)
If A1 has "business" and B1 does not have "??" C1 needs to return "basic"
If A1 has business and B1 contains "??" C1 needs to return "execute"

I have tried using search function , And function but not anle to get result

Answer (score 0):

Try `=IF(A1<>"business","",IF(AND(A1="business",IFERROR(FIND("??",B1),0)=0),"basic",IF(AND(A1="business",IFERROR(FIND("??",B1),0)>0),"execute","")))`

Comment: Formula only answers are frowned upon.  you should explain your formula so other might be able to understand what is going on with it.

Comment: Your formula does work.  If you want to refine it, your AND statement in the nested IF portion is redunt as the only way to get to it is if A1 is equal to business already.  your first IF took care of that.  you do not need your third if statement as your find routine can only be greater than 0 if it found something which you did with your second IF statement where you perform your first iferror.  This is a trimmed down version of your formula: `=IF(A1<>"business","",IF(IFERROR(FIND("??",B1),0)=0,"basic","execute"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1<>"business","",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~??",B1)),"execute","basic"))
```

Place the above in C1.  If you have header row, then you will have to put this in C2 and adjust the cell references to look in the second row.

The first check is to see if A1 is equal to "business".  If it is not it returns "" which is the closest you are going to get to nothing in a cell from an excel formula.

If A1 is equal to business, then it does a search for "??"  The tilde "~" is put in front to prevent Excel from treating it as a wild card.  If it does find it, it will have a number.  The isnumber check will return true if ?? is found and false if ? is not found.